# laravel command line not working for non root users

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Installed laravel command line as per laravel doco  logged in as root

composer global require "laravel/installer"

For a non root user if I set  the PATH inside .bashrc file to PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.composer/vendor/bin

its not be able to access laravel commandline as /root doesnt have execute permission on directory for other users.    How can I make it access across all  non root users?

Comment: What os you are using ?

Comment: You should not use "composer global require" while logged in as root.

Comment: Thanks for the info why I should not use global using amazon linux os